# How to insert animated GIF in LyX Beamer?

Tags: beamer, lyx, animations, gif

I am a very beginner using beamer, but I want to learn how to make a similar "animated GIF" in my presentation, like in this pdf file on the 31th page: https://personal.ntu.edu.sg/nprivault/MA5182/stochastic-calculus-jump-processes.pdf.

The only difference between this pdf and my presentation, that I have a sequence of figures which I want to skip forward and backward on  the same frame, I don't want to generate random numbers.

What shall I do? Sorry if this question has been already asked, but I am really a beginner and I need step by step commands.

Comment: The animation you are referring to was inserted with the `animate` package. It does exactly this: animating a sequence of prefabricated, external image files. But it can also animate graphics that are coded within the document using one of the dedicated LaTeX packages, such as PGFPlots (all sorts of function plots), TikZ or PSTricks (general graphics). There are quite a few examples here on this site (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animate), but also in the [`animate` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf).